# Applications of higher order reciprocity laws

Tags: applications, quadratic-reciprocity, cubic-reciprocity

I'm currently studying quartic & cubic residues and their reciprocity laws, and would like to know of any real world applications to finding the values of their respective residue symbols.

I know that applications of quadratic residues are in cryptography, primality testing, and graph theory. However I have yet to find an application of quartic/cubic residues and specifically using their reciprocity theorems.